# Declaration and format of 2D Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I recently got into an argument with a friend about the declaration of multidimensional arrays in Java.
It would concern the following type of array:

```
int[][] array = new int[2][3];
```

So far so good, but one of us sees this array as 2 arrays, each containing 3 elements, and the other see it as 3 arrays, each containing 2 elements. So person A thinks that this is the correct declaration:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
```

Whereas person B thinks that this is the correct declaration:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}};
```

Who of us is correct? And how could that person prove he's right?

Thanks :)

Comment: i m going for person A..:) for confusion refer http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html

Comment: Great thanks to all of you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following code may shed some light on the way arrays work in Java:

```
int[][] array=new int[1][3];
int[] sub=array[0];
sub[0]=1; sub[1]=2; sub[2]=42;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
array=new int[2][];
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
array[0]=sub; array[1]=sub;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run this code :

```
    int[][] array = new int[2][3];
    System.out.println(array[0].length);
    System.out.println(array[1].length);
```

Output is :

```
3
3
```

That means, that person A is right.

Answer (score 0):

**Person A is correct.**

This output of this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] array1 = new int[2][3];
        //int[][] array2 = new int[3][2];

        System.out.println(intArray2DToString(array1));
        //System.out.println(intArray2DToString(array2));
    }

    /**
     * Converts a 2D int array to a string
     */
    static String intArray2DToString(int[][] array2D)
    {
        String str = "[";
        for(int[] array : array2D)
        {
            str += Arrays.toString(array);
            str += ", ";
        }
        str += "]";
        str = str.replaceAll(", (?=])", "");
        return str;
    }
}
```

is:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int[][] array = new int[2][3];
```

The structure is roughly:

```
[[x, x], [x, x], [x, x]]
```